# Manual Acknowledgement of ActiveMQ Messages with Alpakka

Tags: java, akka, activemq-classic, akka-stream, alpakka

I am working on implementing Akka Alpakka for consuming from and producing to ActiveMQ queues, in Java. I can consume from the queue successfully, but I haven't yet been able to implement application-level message acknowledgement.

My goal is to consume messages from a queue and send them to another actor for processing. When that actor has completed processing, I want it to be able control the acknowledgement of the message in ActiveMQ. Presumably this would be done by sending a message to another actor that can do the acknowledgement, calling an acknowledge function on the message itself, or some other way.

In my test, 2 messages are put into the AlpakkaTest queue, and then this code attempts to consume and acknowledge them. However, I don't see a way to set the ActiveMQ session to CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE, and I don't see any difference in behavior with or without the call to `m.acknowledge();`. Because of this, I think messages are still being auto-acknowledged.

Does anyone know the accepted way to configure ActiveMQ sessions for CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE and manually acknowledge ActiveMQ messages in Java Akka systems using Alpakka?

The relevant test function is:

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://0.0.0.0:2999"); // An embedded broker running in the test.

Source<Message, NotUsed> jmsSource = JmsSource.create(
    JmsSourceSettings.create(connectionFactory)
        .withQueue("AlpakkaTest")
        .withBufferSize(2)
);

Materializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system); // `system` is an ActorSystem passed to the function.

try {
    List<Message> messages = jmsSource
        .take(2)
        .runWith(Sink.seq(), materializer)
        .toCompletableFuture().get(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    for(Message m:messages) {
        System.out.println("Found Message ID: " + m.getJMSMessageID());

        try {
            m.acknowledge();
        } catch(JMSException jmsException) {
            System.out.println("Acknowledgement Failed for Message ID: " + m.getJMSMessageID() + " (" + jmsException.getLocalizedMessage() + ")");
        }
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (TimeoutException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (JMSException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code prints:

```
Found Message ID: ID:jmstest-43178-1503343061195-1:26:1:1:1
Found Message ID: ID:jmstest-43178-1503343061195-1:27:1:1:1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: The acknowledgement mode is configurable in the JMS connector since Alpakka [0.15](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/0.15/jms.html#receiving-s-messages-from-a-jms-provider-with-client-acknowledgement). From the linked documentation:

```
Source<Message, NotUsed> jmsSource = JmsSource.create(JmsSourceSettings
    .create(connectionFactory)
    .withQueue("test")
    .withAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.ClientAcknowledge())
);

CompletionStage<List<String>> result = jmsSource
    .take(msgsIn.size())
    .map(message -> {
        String text = ((ActiveMQTextMessage)message).getText();
        message.acknowledge();
        return text;
    })
    .runWith(Sink.seq(), materializer);
```

---

As of version 0.11, Alpakka's JMS connector does not support application-level message acknowledgment. Alpakka creates internally a `Session` with the `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` mode [here](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/v0.11/jms/src/main/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/jms/JmsConnector.scala#L60) and acknowledges each message [here](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/v0.11/jms/src/main/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/jms/JmsSourceStage.scala#L67) in the internal `MessageListener`. The API does not expose these settings for overriding.

There is an open [ticket](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/issues/104) that discusses enabling downstream acknowledgement of queue-based sources, but that ticket has been inactive for a while.

Currently you cannot prevent Alpakka from acknowledging the messages at the JMS level. However, that doesn't preclude you from adding a stage to your stream that sends each message to an actor for processing and uses the actor's replies as backpressure signals. The Akka Streams [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/java/stream/stream-integrations.html#integrating-with-actors) describes how to do this with either a combination of `mapAsync` and `ask` or with `Sink.actorRefWithAck`. For example, to use the former:

```
Timeout askTimeout = Timeout.apply(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

jmsSource
    .mapAsync(2, msg -> ask(processorActor, msg, askTimeout))
    .runWith(Sink.seq(), materializer);
```

(Side note: In the related Streamz project, there is a recently opened [ticket](https://github.com/krasserm/streamz/issues/40) to allow application-level acknowledgement. Streamz is the replacement for the old akka-camel module and, like Alpakka, is built on Akka Streams. Streamz also has a Java API and is [listed](http://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/external-connectors.html#camel) in the Alpakka documentation as an external connector.)

Comment: Thanks. The ack requirement is more around message integrity, but applying backpressure in this way is definitely good information. I'll investigate Streamz some, too.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code for the Alpakka JmsSourceStage it already acknowledges each incoming message for you (and it's session is a Client Ack session).  From what I can tell from the source there is no mode that allows you to do the acknowledgement of messages.

You can view the source code for Alpakka [here](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/master/jms/src/main/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/jms/JmsSourceStage.scala).